# Checking for Multiple Conditions in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

It checks for multiple conditions no problem. But doesn't go any further then that. When i remove multiple conditions, script works perfectly fine. What is wrong with my code?

````
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("car-club-insurance") || window.location.href.indexOf("motor-home-hire-insurance") || window.location.href.indexOf("van-minibus-hire-insurance") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("FormTwo") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("FormThree") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("PolicyHolder") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("Payment") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(9)").addClass("active");
        }         
    });
</script> ```
````

Comment: Your code is malformed. indexof() or indexof() != -1 is incorrect. it should be indexof() != -1 or indexof() != -1

Comment: @NawedKhan can't see the difference

Comment: @freedomn-m using indexof() without a comparison will always return true because it always returns a number.

Comment: @NawedKhan Your earlier comment reads as: "indexof() != -1 is incorrect it should be indexof() != -1"

Comment: @freedomn-m no it reads " indexof() or indexof() != -1" is incorrect. I should have put the quotes to void confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The code is malformed. indexof() always returns an int hence checking if(indexof()) will always be true. You need to put a comparison with each check like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("car-club-insurance") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("motor-home-hire-insurance") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("van-minibus-hire-insurance") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("FormTwo") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("FormThree") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("PolicyHolder") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(7)").addClass("active");
        }
        else if
        (window.location.href.indexOf("Payment") != -1) {
            $("ol.breadcrumb li:nth-child(9)").addClass("active");
        }         
    });
```